# Problem when importing package in scala

Tags: scala, package

Suppose I have such packages:

```
package test
package test.views
package test.others
package views
```

Now in a scala file, I want to import `test._` and `views._`(not `test.views._`), so I write:

```
import test._
import views._
```

But when I use some classes under `views._`, it reports `type xxx not found`, unless I change `views` package to another name.

What should I do now?

Comment: In the second code snippet you write `package`, but your intent is to `import` them, no?

Comment: package and import are 2 different concepts. You should make it clear which exactly are you asking. Also, what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch package import order (theoretically it should work):

```
import views._
import test._
```

Or you can be more precise in `views` import:

```
import _root_.views._
```

Comment: This illustrate a very good example of why you should never use wildcard imports because of name collisions.

Comment: @Y.H Wong: Please, allow me to disagree. Yes, collisions happen and it's easy to solve them. But to say "you should never use wildcard imports" is incorrect IMHO. Fact, that there exist exceptions does not mean that we should completely forbid this feature. In my Java/Scala experience there were very few of them and each time it was very easy to fix.

Comment: It's a very well established best practice in languages like Java and Python that you should never use wildcard imports in Any serious code because of the the possibility of leading to some very hard to find bugs. The experience in these communities haven't crossed-pollinated yet it seems. Wildcard imports may only be used when prototyping in the REPL for convenience. In the ideal world, the Scala compiler could issue us warnings when asked to, but no such feature exist yet.

Comment: @Y.H Wong: Can you, please, provide some links to support your statements: "It's a very well established best practice" and "leading to some very hard to find bugs"

Comment: Google "import * considered harmful" for Java. For Python, go check out Python's tutorial section 6.4.1. I quote it for your reference here "Although certain modules are designed to export only names that follow certain patterns when you use import *, it is still considered bad practise in production code.". There's a reason why all the IDEs default to list out all your imported names when you format your source code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another way (though using `_root_` is the surest way to go):

```
import test.{views => testviews, _}
import views._
```